# CS1061: does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Why I get this error? Of course SelectIssuePriority doesn't exist on my first model. I have add it.

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Devcore' does not contain a definition for 'SelectIssuePriority' and no extension method 'SelectIssuePriority' accepting a first argument of type 'Devcore.' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 77: 
Line 78:         <div class="editor-label">
Line 79:             <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectIssuePriority) %>
Line 80:         </div>
Line 81:         <div class="editor-field">
```

Model

```
namespace Devcore.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(IssueMetaData))]
    public partial class Issue
    {

    }


    public class IssueMetaData 
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Summary is required",AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Summary { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Priority")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Priority is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string SelectIssuePriority { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Aspx

```
<div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectIssuePriority) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.DropDownList("SelectIssuePriority") %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectIssuePriority) %>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, those `MetaData` extension classes are purely for validation. If your base model doesn't have those properties.. it won't work.

So you need this for the view to accept that properties exist:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IssueMetaData))]
public partial class Issue
{
    public string SelectIssuePriority { get; set; }
}
```

And you need the `MetaData` class for the `DataAnnotations` to work with model validation.