# Read binary to List<T>

Tags: c#, list, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to create a list of quotes that are saved to a file. Once the quotes are shown on the console I'll change the bool to true. The index is used to handle which quote to show on the console. First I tried File.WriteAllLines, but that will not work with my Quotes-class.

It seems that my attempts to serialize the list to file will work ok but I can't figure out how to get rid of CS1061 in the code that should read from the file to myList2.

I would really like some feedback on this. The code is just for my own learning and amusement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Quotes
{
    // A quote followed by a bool to show if it has been showed recently and an index to navigate the list.
    [Serializable]
    class Quotes
    {
        private string quote;
        private bool shown;
        private int index;
        public Quotes(string _quote, bool _shown, int _index)
        {
            quote = _quote;
            shown = _shown;
            index = _index;
        }

        public string Quote
        {
            get
            {
                return quote;
            }
            set
            {
                quote = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Shown
        {
            get
            {
                return shown;
            }
            set
            {
                shown = value;
            }
        }

        public int Index
        {
            get
            {
                return index;
            }
            set
            {
                index = value;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", quote, shown, index);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set a variable to the My Documents path.
            string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            //List<Quotes> myList = new List<Quotes>();
            var myList = new List<Quotes>();
            myList.Add(new Quotes("One", false, 1));
            myList.Add(new Quotes("Two", false, 2));
            myList.Add(new Quotes("Three", false, 3));
            myList.Add(new Quotes("Four", false, 4));
            //Write the list to a file. Expand to accept user input and add at the end of the file.
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = File.Open(mydocpath + @"\WriteLines.txt", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                    bin.Serialize(stream, myList);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }

            //Read from a file and write to the list.Put in a method when it works.
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = File.Open(mydocpath + @"\WriteLines.txt", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                    var myList2 = (List<Quotes>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
                    foreach (var quote in myList2)
                    {
                        //Why is this not working? Where should I define quote??
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", myList2.quote, myList2.shown, myList2.index);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For review of your code this is the correct place for second question : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: First piece of feedback: format your code. Second piece of feedback: Learn about automatically implemented properties. Third piece of feedback: provide a [mcve] which would be shorter than this and more precise about the error.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501120/cs1061-does-not-contain-a-definition-for

Comment: @PriyankKapadia: It sounds like it's not *really* code review (that was my first thought too) as the OP is trying to get rid of an error, and can't work out how to do so.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought there were two questions by OP. The first one was for a solution and second one was for feedback. I might be wrong though my bad.

Comment: @PriyankKapadia: It's certainly not entirely clear - but I'd say that while the code doesn't work, it's on-topic here rather than in code review.

Comment: `catch (IOException) {}` — Dear god, why? WHY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently your code attempts to access `myList2.quote`, but even within the `foreach` block, `myList2` is still the list itself, not the "current item within that list".

`foreach` assigns each individual `Quote` object in the list to the `var quote` variable. Within the `foreach` block you can then access the properties of that quote using:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", quote.Quote, quote.Shown, quote.Index);
```

(note that `quote.quote` is a private field, while `quote.Quote` is the public property you can access)

Answer (score 2):

Your foreach loop creates an instance of each quote in the list every time it runs, in the variable named quote

```
foreach (var quote in myList2)
```

Therefore you should reference that variable in the code within the loop.

```
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", quote.Quote, quote.Shown, quote.Index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a bunch. I managed to confuse myself. Now it is evident where I blundered.

It is also evident that I need to work on where and how to post on this site. Thanks for being gentle with a noob like me.